# Chrome incorrectly marking our domain without a hyphen as deceptive when we own and use both versions

Tags: security, google-chrome, malware

Chrome has a fairly new "lookalike URL" or "typo squatting" detection feature.  The aim is to warn users if they are accidentally going to the wrong URL.

We own two sites (made up version below):

1. `ourcompanyinc.example`
2. `ourcompany-inc.example`

For whatever reason, the URL without the hyphen is our main web URL, and the URL with the hyphen is used for some other things.

Unfortunately when users go to the non-hyphen version, they are warned that it may be a malicious site, and they should go to the one with the hyphen.  We own both of them.  Does anyone know how we can let Chrome know that they are not lookalikes, so we can avoid this warning?  The warning verbiage is below:

> Did you mean `ourcompany-inc.example`?
>
> Attackers sometimes mimic sites by making hard-to-see changes to the web address.

Comment: Could you merge the content on the two domains onto one domain to prevent confusion?

Comment: It's possible, but it would be a significant project.  I don't like the idea of adjusting our domain structure as a reaction to Google's features, as that would be a moving target.  We also wouldn't be guaranteed that the 1 domain we pick would be seen by google as the primary (non "malicious") domain.

Comment: Making Google happy is a moving target, but unfortunately webmasters often don't have any choice but to try to do so.

Comment: Are both domains verified under the same owner in GSC? If not then that would be the #1 thing to try. ("and the URL with the hyphen is used for some other things" - hhmmm, that is a bit confusing.)

Comment: For clarity, by "other things" I mean it has other (non-primary) websites as subdomains on the URL with the hyphen.  We don't have a GSC setup for the hyphen domain yet - I'll give that a try!

Comment: If the same company owns both websites, it doesn't make much sense to serve different content. I understand the warning, and it seems correct as it can confuse a human visitor who visits the "wrong one" and looks at something different than expected. If possible, I would try to delete the content on one of the sites and 301 redirect everything to the other site. If you absolutely need them to be different, you could use the content as a subdomain of one of the sites (myapp.ourcompanyinc.example).

Answer (score -2):

Chrome is mistakenly flagging your domain without a hyphen as deceptive, despite your ownership and use of both versions. This issue can potentially harm your website's reputation and user trust. To address this problem, you should:

Contact Google Safe Browsing: Reach out to Google Safe Browsing to report the false positive and request a review of your domain.

Check Domain Configuration: Ensure your domain's DNS and SSL configurations are correctly set up for both versions (with and without a hyphen).

Implement Security Measures: Enhance your website's security measures, including regular malware scans and ensuring your site doesn't contain any malicious content.

Monitor for Updates: Keep an eye on Chrome updates, as false positives can sometimes be resolved through browser updates.

By taking these steps, you can work to resolve the issue and prevent further mislabeling of your website by Chrome.

Comment: Did this come from chatgpt?

Comment: Reaching out to Google is usually hard to do.  In this case they do have a form to fill out to report false positives: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en  However, I don't think they are going to accept a request to review your domain.